# GTK+ menu bar looks terrible

Tags: gtk, menubar

I'm writing a Gtk+ menu bar following the instruction [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/x1572.html).

When packing the bar onto a VBox with

```
// "FALSE, TRUE" and "FALSE, FALSE" actually makes no difference
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_vbox), menu_bar,
                   TRUE, FALSE, 0);
```

the menu bar looks terrible, like this:

[image: slim menu bar]

And when I changed to:

```
 gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_vbox), menu_bar,
                    TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

it looks like:

[image]

So, how to make the toolbar get a smaller space allocated?

Comment: Does it not have a special spot to put it? I'm not familiar with that aspect of GTK, but I know that Qt's QMainWindow has a specific spot for a menu bar to go; it has three spots in it - the menu bar, the central widget and the status bar.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Oops. I made a mistake. Sorry. I modified my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to:

1. Get rid of the light gray padding around the menu bar.
2. Do the above without expanding the menu bar to fill the available space.

Therefore, the packing mode of your *other* widget (namely the button bar below your menu bar) comes into play (for clarity, I'll refer to them as `button_hbox` and `menu_bar`, respectively, since both can qualify as "toolbars").

Understanding the boolean layout arguments passed to [gtk_box_pack_start()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-pack-start) is paramount here:

- The first one, `expand`, is `TRUE` if the widget should consume the empty space left in its container after layout is computed. Widgets packed this way compete equally for the remaining space.
- The second one, `fill`, is `TRUE` if the widget should fill the layout space it consumes instead of being centered within it (there comes the light gray padding).

The idea is that you have one (or more, but let's stick to one for now) main widget in `main_vbox`, and that widget is packed with both `expand` and `fill` set to `TRUE`. The satellite widgets around it are packed with `expand` set to `FALSE` and `fill` set to `TRUE`. For instance:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|  Menu bar: expand = FALSE, fill = TRUE    |
+-------------------------------------------+
|  Toolbar: expand = FALSE, fill = TRUE     |
+-------------------------------------------+  ^
|                                           |  |
|                                           |  |  The height of this widget
|  Main widget: expand = TRUE, fill = TRUE  |  |  varies depending on the 
|                                           |  |  height of its container.
|                                           |  |
+-------------------------------------------+  v
|  Status bar: expand = FALSE, fill = TRUE  |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

In your case, since you don't want `menu_bar` to fill the available space, `button_hbox` should do so:

```
// Menu bar: satellite widget, expand = FALSE, fill = TRUE
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_vbox), menu_bar, FALSE, TRUE, 0);

// Button bar: main widget, expand = TRUE, fill = TRUE
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main_vbox), button_hbox, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

Comment: Apologies for the ugly ASCII art, I'm old school :)